# Program stops unexpected in python after it does an encryption algorithm

Tags: python, encryption, pysimplegui

So I made an GUI in python and encryption program:
This is the layout

```
layout=[[sg.Text('Enter message'),sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Text('Cryptation key'),sg.Input(key='-KEY-')],
    [sg.Text('Answer',key='-OUT-')],
    [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('EXIT')]
    ]
```

This is the while loop:

```
while True:
event, values=window.read()
if event is None or event == 'EXIT':
    break
mesaj=str('-IN-').upper()
cheie=str('-KEY-').upper()
key=generate_key(mesaj,cheie)
encrypt_text=encrypt_vigenere(mesaj,key)
window['-OUT-'].update(values[encrypt_text])
```

window.close()

Here is the function that I think is thee problem:

```
def encrypt_vigenere(message,key_word):
key = generate_key(message,key_word)

encrypted_text = ""

for i in range(0,len(message)):
    if message[i] == " ":
        encrypted_text += " "
    else:
        encryption_value = (alphabets.find(message[i]) + alphabets.find(key[i]))%26
        encrypted_text += alphabets[encryption_value]

return encrypted_text
```

And it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/flavius/Documents/python/games/urs_mina/main.py", line 62, in 
window['-OUT-'].update(values[encrypt_text])
KeyError: 'YSRX'

Every time I press OK ti shows the message above. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Because your `values` dictionary does not have an entry for `'YSRX'`.  Why did you think it did?  And by the way, saying `str('-IN-").upper()` is silly; that value (and '-KEY-') are already strings and already upper case.

Comment: Is it possible you just meant to say `window['-OUT-'].update( encrypt_text )`?

Comment: No. I tried to change the code and it gives me the same error, the only difference being: KeyError: 'MSRE'. Also, i tryed the same program but without the GUI and it works. But when I decomment the GUI it shows me the error.

Comment: I assume you understand that "YSRX" and "MSRE" are both the results of running your encryption scheme.  Why do you think those values will be in the `values` dict?

Comment: I tryed this
`def encryption(string, key):
    encrypt_text = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        x = (ord(string[i]) + ord(key[i])) % 26
        x += ord('A')
        encrypt_text.append(chr(x))
    return ("".join(encrypt_text))
`
It works when I comment the GUI and use main. But if I use the GUI it crashes. If I do it in main it encrypts just fime.

Comment: You don't understand what's going on here.  Your encryption function is not the problem.  The problem happens in `window['-OUT-'].update(values[encrypt_text])`, because you are trying to look up the entry in the `values` dictionary that has your encrypted text as a key, and there is no such value.  What do you think that statement is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get value of element `sg.Input` in event loop by

```py
mesaj = values['-IN-'].upper()
cheie = values['-KEY-'].upper()
```

To update value of element `sg.Output` by

```py
window['-OUT-'].update(encrypt_text)
```

`window[key]` for element, `values[key]` for values dictionary with element key.

If you get wrong arguments for function `encrypt_vigenere`, you may also get wrong result, IMO, it's not the problem here.